# Strange notation for Python 3 bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, byte, python-3.5

Can someone identify what this notation for these `bytes` is? At first glance, I tend to think "hexadecimal", but I don't recognize what things like `xf1Y` and `e1fl` are:

```
b'vy\xe9\xb5\xa2\xba\xf1Y\xe8\xe1fl\x1d\x87\xacC'
```

I get this when I encode things using `some_text.encode('utf-8')`.

I am trying to get bytes that I can pass to cryptography methods that worked with Python 2's byte strings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're right – it's a hexadecimal notation.

In a bytes literal, any byte which can't be represented by a printable ASCII character (or one of the standard escapes `\n`, `\t` or `\r`) is represented as `\xNN`, where NN is the 2-digit hexadecimal representation of the byte.

What's confusing you is that you're mistaking e.g. `\xf1Y` for a single escape sequence, when in fact it represents two separate bytes:

```
>>> len(b'\xf1Y')
2
>>> [bytes([b]) for b in b'\xf1Y']
[b'\xf1', b'Y']
```

If you iterate over a bytes object, you'll get the integer values of the bytes back:

```
>>> list(b'vy\xe9\xb5\xa2\xba\xf1Y\xe8\xe1fl\x1d\x87\xacC')
[118, 121, 233, 181, 162, 186, 241, 89, 232, 225, 102, 108, 29, 135, 172, 67]
>>> bytes([118])
b'v'
>>> bytes([121])
b'y'
>>> bytes([233])
b'\xe9'
```

The documentation for [escape sequences in Python string and bytes objects](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-18) has a little more information on escape sequences Python understands (although those above are the only ones it uses to represent bytes objects).

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, that is what was confusing me.  I did not know it was mixing literal character depictions alongside the /x__ hex codes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understood this. *-*

Comment: Is there a reason why they are not just consistent with having everything as `\xAB`?